# How can I calculate a date in a Django model?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I spent most of the day yesterday trying to find an answer, but couldn't figure out how to add the decorator to the model.

Goal: Calculate a date, based on the user entering the number of days.
Use Case: User enters the "start date", and the number of days in a form.
For example, the user enters a start date of 1/1/2017, and days = 5.  The calc date should be 1/6/2017.

I could not get the calculated field to pull through on my template.

Code snippets below.

```
#models.py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from django.db import models 
from django_extensions.db.models import TimeStampedModel
from django.urls import reverse


class Lease(TimeStampedModel):
    location_name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    contingency_start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    contingency_period_in_days = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
    def __str__(self):
        return self.location_name

@property
    def get_contingency_end_date(self):
        return datetime.date(self.contingency_start_date) +       
                     timedelta(days=self.contingency_period_in_days)
```

## views.py

```
class LeaseDetailView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Lease

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LeaseDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['options_list'] = Option.objects.all()
        return context
```

## detail.html

```
<li><strong>Start date</strong> {{ lease.contingency_start_date }}</li>
<li><strong>contingency_in_days </strong> {{ lease.contingency_period_in_days }}</li>
```

## not working

```
<li><strong>End date: </strong> {{ lease.get_contingency_end_date }}</li>
```

Comment: *pull through on my template.* How do you mean?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye - by pull thru, I mean that the calculated value is not displaying in the html template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a `@propery` method is accessed like a normal property call it `contingency_end_date`. No get as a prefix. consider using a [cached_propery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property).

You do not have to wrap your date field into a `datetime.date`. It already is a `date` object when fetched from the database.

```
@cached_property
def contingency_end_date(self):
    return self.contingency_start_date +       
                 timedelta(days=self.contingency_period_in_days)
```

Accessing it in the template should work with `{{ lease.contingency_end_date }}`

Did you verify that your `lease` instance actually has a `contingency_start_date` set?

Comment: amazing!  you added a few hairs back on my head!  Thanks.

Comment: Yeah but you should also consider the case when your start date is None or make the field not nullable. Otherwise the method could throw an error.